# iOS Universal, only 1 path segment

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I want to craft a path for Universal Link that are only valid when there's 1 folder segment. Like:

```
https://example.com/first or https://example.com/first/
```

but I don't want it to come into my app when the URL is:

```
https://example.com/first/second
https://example.com/first/index.html
https://example.com/first/second/script.js
https://example.com/first/second/third/image.png
```

I am using this AASA JSON

```
"appID": "<appid>",
"paths": [ 
  "*/*.aspx",
  "NOT /first/*/*",
  "/first/*/"
]
```

It doesn't work. How can I control this by number of path segment?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the `*` is that you will include any string combination including the empty string. I would suggest trying to add a `?` character followed by a `*` to ensure that the string cannot be empty. In your case, try:

```
"appID": "<appid>",
"paths": [ 
   "*/*.aspx",
   "/?*", //Include paths that have '/first/'
   "NOT /?*/?*" //For paths that have '/first/second/third' etc
]
```

Hopefully, that works for you.